# GET via jQuery em um server diferente, problema com CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

Estou tentando fazer uma chamada `GET/AJAX` para uma `URL` que é diferente da que estou fazendo a chamada, mas sempre recebo a mensagem no browser:

> Failed to load http://urldoserver.com/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://meuserver.com/' is therefore not allowed access.

Eu já tentei fazer tanto em servidor `Apache` como `NGINX` e habilitar de várias formas o `CORS` de acordo com a documentação e algumas dicas. Até tentei via `PHP` adicionar o `header`:

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

Mas sempre recebo a mensagem de bloqueio do `CORS`. Via `POSTMAN` a chamada ocorre normalmente.

Eu devo solicitar ao administrador do servidor que libere o IP do meu servidor para realizar as chamadas ou eu estou configurando erroneamente o CORS ou a chamada do meu lado no servidor?

Answer (score 3):

Respondendo a própria pergunta, toda questão se resume que eu estava sempre tentando fazer uma requisição POST/GET para uma URL diferente da minha mas, fazendo isso através do browser, ou seja, no client-side.

Quando na verdade eu deveria estar fazendo isso no server-side, ou seja, usando PHP (cURL), Node.JS (HTTP Request).

O bloqueio acontece exatamente porque o browser é proibido de fazer esse tipo de ação e sempre vai resultar com o erro de CORS.

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber, tem alguma forma de eu criar uma API em JSON e consumir ela de dentro de um dos arquivos da aplicação?

Comment: Sem problemas, porque a aplicação irá consumir em localhost sua API.

Comment: ahhhh, neste caso o URL ficaria como `localhost:8100` (localhost genérico)?

Comment: Isso mesmo, se sua API está na porta 8100 é só chamar com essa URL. Tipo `http://localhost:8100/alguma_rota`

Comment: Valeu, salvou o meu TCC

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo uma requisição `AJAX` para um domínio diferente do que a sua página está ativada. Portanto, o navegador está bloqueando isso, pois geralmente permite um pedido na mesma origem por motivos de segurança. Você precisa fazer algo diferente quando quiser fazer um pedido de domínio cruzado. Um tutorial sobre como conseguir isso com [CORS (tanto com `AJAX` quanto com `XMLHttpRequest` )](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Quando você está usando o `POSTMAN`, eles não estão restritos por esta política. Citação de [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) :

> Páginas web regulares podem usar o objeto XMLHttpRequest para enviar e
>   receber dados de servidores remotos, mas eles são limitados pela mesma
>   política de origem. As extensões não são tão limitadas. Uma extensão
>   pode conversar com servidores remotos fora da sua origem, desde que
>   primeiro solicite permissões de origem cruzada.

Comment: Eu havia passado por esse tutorial ontem, realizei novo teste hoje e mesmo assim ele continua apontando o bloqueio no navegador.  Agora o que é engraçado, ao menos neste caso dessa URL que estou fazendo a chamada é que apesar de aparecer o erro no console, ele está dando um response positivo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu criei uma classe para auxiliar a resolver este problema:

```
/*
* Função Auxiliar para resolver o problema no chrome
*/

Auxi::Cors();
```

> Aqui está a classe:

```
<?php


final class Auxi{


    public static function Cors() {

        // Allow from any origin
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
        }

        // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
                // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

            exit(0);
        }
    }

    private function __construct()
    {

    }
}
?>
```